# Live stream on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I'm developing an Android application that allow the users to watch the tv channels via streaming.

The user must "tap" on the channel (for example chan 1) and an activity show the real time video, but I have one question, there are other solutions, different by the use of a webview to show the live video ?

Exist some solutions more "professional" or functionals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) to play streams. Take a look at the [DemoApp](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo). As official documentation says

> ExoPlayer has support for Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH)
>   and SmoothStreaming, neither of which are are supported by MediaPlayer
>   (it also supports HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), MP4, MP3, WebM, M4A,
>   MPEG-TS and AAC).

But make sure you can get the direct link to your streams.